# while streaming video from google drive , there is an error in audio

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, video-streaming

hlw ,

I m trying to play video into my website from google drive , which file (video) is public and
it has an audio . file is processed and viewable in drive.

File Id  : **1gEFgIazCYHDwBOdXLNPr6j5dSHPopp_a**

**my file streaming url : https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1gEFgIazCYHDwBOdXLNPr6j5dSHPopp_a?alt=media&key=AIzaSyBltd-lU2bYV7GCHJ42TtqN3pouQMvZ1v4**

if i embaded this link into video tag it is not playing audio.

```html
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1gEFgIazCYHDwBOdXLNPr6j5dSHPopp_a?alt=media&key=AIzaSyBltd-lU2bYV7GCHJ42TtqN3pouQMvZ1v4" type="video/mp4">
 
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```

Can someone please help me to play audio in this file.

**When i Try to play This File From Ifram Of drive It is working Fine , but i want to play from Direct Video tag**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file you are trying to play in  an MKV file , as per as chrome doesn't support MKV file stream

[image]

but you can try to play link in native video player in android by using : -

```
<a href="intent://googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1gEFgIazCYHDwBOdXLNPr6j5dSHPopp_a?alt=media&key=AIzaSyBltd-lU2bYV7GCHJ42TtqN3pouQMvZ1v4#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;scheme=http;type=video/mp4;end">Intent: Link; will play in app</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google drive is not a file hosting service it was not intended for this use.

you will end up hitting the daily sharing limit as well if you continue in this manner.

may I suggest you upload it to your web server which is designed for hosting files for website